# Apache Tomcat 7 and Eclipse Juno EE integration (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

I am currently setting up a Web Service environment for developing SOAP Web services in a linux box (Ubuntu 12.04). I want to use Eclipse EE Juno with Apache Tomcat 7. I successfully install tomcat (using the sudo apt-get install) and configure it as a Server runtime environment in Eclipse. When, I deploy a web service in order to test it, everything works fine. However, when I type the URL to my browser, nothing works. It seems that Apache tomcat is up and running, but no web services are deployed (in fact i receive an HTTP Status 404 from tomcat). Being curious, I go to "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/" directory in order to check if any web application is deployed, and there are no web applications.
What may be the matter? How can I configure correctly my tomcat in order to work with Eclipse and be able to deploy and test my web applications through the IDE?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but the default Server environment in Eclipse (both on Ubuntu and Windows) doesn't deploy wars to the Tomcat installation; instead they exist in your Eclipse workspace directory, in a sub folder called "Servers". So it's OK to not see anything deployed in your "actual" Tomcat directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by configuring to IDE to have all the pribileges on the server.